# Trying to access the account (Preview) REST API in Keycloak , getting a 404

Tags: keycloak, jboss-tools, keycloak-services

I am trying to access the new account API (Not the Admin) in `keycloak 4.8.3` . I am trying to do :

```
GET "/auth/realms/{realm}/account/credentials/password" endpoint (Based on the AccountRestServiceTest.java)
```

with the account owner's token. Getting a `404 error`.

I have started the sever with preview features

```
bin/standalone.bat -Dkeycloak.profile=preview
```

I have tried to add `profile.properites` file with `profile=preview` options

and the user has `"manage-account"`,`"view-profile"` account roles

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem and i found a solution.

You need to add the HTTP header **Accept** with the value **application/json** to your request.

Because AccountRestService is only accessible if headers **Accept** or **Content-Type** are application/json.